Is there a way to connect the idea of an increase in physical information with the idea that logical systems can have “more information”?
Is there a way to connect the idea that the universe is expanding with information theory? If the universe is bigger, doesn’t that mean it contains “more stuff”, more information?
I asked this to Claude 3.5 Sonnet and these are a couple things it said that are relevant:


Expanding Universe: The expansion of the universe refers to the observation that galaxies are moving away from each other, and the
space between them is increasing. This doesn't necessarily mean the
universe contains "more stuff" in the traditional sense.

Conservation of Matter and Energy: According to our current understanding, the total amount of matter and energy in the observable
universe remains constant. The expansion doesn't create new matter or
energy.

Information in Cosmology: In cosmology, information is often related to the arrangement and state of matter and energy, rather than
their absolute quantity. As the universe expands, it's not gaining new
particles or energy, but the relationships between existing components
are changing.

Entropy and Information: There's a deep connection between information theory and entropy. As the universe expands and cools, it
generally moves towards a state of higher entropy. In information
theory, higher entropy can be associated with more information in some
contexts, but it's crucial to understand what we mean by "information"
here.

Holographic Principle: Some theoretical approaches, like the holographic principle, suggest that the information content of a
volume of space can be described by information on its boundary
surface. As the universe expands, this boundary surface grows,
potentially allowing for more information to be encoded.

Quantum Information: In quantum mechanics, the expansion of space could potentially lead to the creation of quantum entanglement between
previously unconnected regions, which could be seen as creating new
quantum information.

Observable Universe vs. Entire Universe: As the universe expands, our observable universe (the part we can see) actually contains more
galaxies over time, as light from previously unreachable regions
becomes visible to us. This could be interpreted as gaining access to
more information, even if it existed before.

Information Paradox: The expansion of the universe plays a role in various cosmological puzzles, including the black hole information
paradox, which deals with whether information is truly lost when it
falls into a black hole.


While the expansion of the universe doesn't create new matter or
energy, it does change the structure and relationships within the
cosmos in ways that could be interpreted as creating or revealing new
information.  The connection between cosmological expansion and information theory
is not straightforward and depends heavily on how we define and
measure "information" in this context.

I want to understand more precisely how to apply the idea of “information in a physical system” to “information in a logical system” - that is, that different formal systems, say, generate “universes” which are actually “bigger” than others in terms of the amount of distinct information they have. Maybe the smallest possible logical theory is some equational theory which says that all objects in the domain are equal to one another, for example. I think a distinction should be made between “size” of a theory versus “amount of information” in a theory, though they are possibly related.

It would improve your post if you would first define "information in a physical system" and "information in a logical system", and then focus on a precise question how the two concepts relate to each other. Tell us the relevant state of the art in cosmology and information theory. - This site is not intended for assessing the output of AI or to communicate your personal conjecture that "the smallest possible logical theory is some equational theory".

My general sense is that "information" in logic concerns objects in general, p's and q's, and a specified number of relationships those objects can have.  Math and logic are always coming up with new relationships, imaginary numbers and paraconsistent logic and the like, but the difference between information in logic and empirical information is between finite epistemological relationships and infinite sense material.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75146/entropy-and-information

Also asking about the ramblings.or an LLM answer is probably off-topic, this site exists to discuss works of philosophy.

@tkruse The question stands entirely on its own without the AI answer (even though I think quoting AIs is often unnecessary or in bad taste), so this is no reason to consider it off topic

I won't answer since I don't know any information theory, but it seems that the question of whether an increase in size of the universe implies an increase in information is identical to the question of whether the universe is deterministic or not (i.e. whether or not each state of the universe is derivable from the previous state and therefore adds no unknown information)

Point 7 should be just the reverse! Over time -- assuming the earth would still exist -- we would lose information if expansion continues. The night sky would become totally dark. Winter is coming.


If the universe is bigger, doesn’t that mean it contains “more stuff”, more information?

Not necessarily.
Suppose you have a filled water balloon under high pressure. The amount of water in the balloon is a fixed amount. Now the balloon pops and all the water in the balloon expands outward. The water is now spread out over a much larger volume than the original container but the amount of water hasn't changed. It is the density of the water (water per volume) that has decreased.
The act of filling the balloon is an example of expansion due to an increase in the amount of water in the balloon.
This is a nice visualization to show the difference between:
-Expansion: Volume increases without mass change.
-Growth: Both volume and mass increase.

Is there a way to connect the idea of an increase in physical information with the idea that logical systems can have “more information”?

Let's use a switch to represent a simple two state logic system that represents a number (message). 1 is On 0 is off.
How many switches can be used to represent the number 1 in binary?
Ans: A minimum of one but the maximum is infinite.
1  001 0001 ...0000001  etc.
Suppose I start with one switch set to one and I wish to add another switch without altering the original number (message). My only choice is to add a switch to the left of the original set to 0 (OFF). If the switch is set to the right the number becomes 10 or 2 which is a new number or message. If the new switch is set to 1 then another new unique number/message 11 or 3 is created.
So an increase in physical information can be designed in a manner to either preserve original information and add the potential to store larger numbers or create new information each time a switch is added.

So with Shannon information, the core of what we’re looking at is the choice of an element from a set; specifically the set of possible messages that might be communicated over an information channel.
I don’t think the question of the size of the totality of the universe is an information theory question so much as it is a Set theory question.  One potentially interesting field is Determinacy, which looks at the relationship between certain signal games being well defined and the existence of large cardinalities.

You ask:

Is there a way to connect the idea of an increase in physical information with the idea that logical systems can have “more information”?

It depends on whether you subscribe to it from bit or not. John Archibald Wheeler famously rekindled subjective idealism in contemporary physics with his Participatory Anthropic Principle by recycling the old thinking that bits exist because minds bring them into existence. This is an interpretation of QM roughly that says that minds bring the universe into existence. If you subscribe to these metaphysical principles, then an increase in minds (and presumably, the universe is chock-full of them), then there is an increase in the universe itself to do logic with.
A physicalist on the other hand will view the computing medium as the physical substrate, and therefore interpret your question in the light of bigger and bigger computers which incorporate more bits and information. Up until Babbage, computers (and by computers I mean what we can infer existed based upon the Antikythera mechanism) were small, astronomical devices and almost non-existent. Mechanical computers emerged in the 19th century, and by WWII, electromechanical computers were being built. Now, computers, and by their virtues, bits and information, are now essentially ubiquitous.
Thus, in both senses of the word, as the number of sentient beings (again, presumably rather common in the cosmos) expands and builds more and more computers, more and more mass and energy is converted to use for computers, for creating more and more bits. And since computers tend to be used to benefit us, to help us grow more crops, manage our affairs, one could speculate that this is a positive feed back loop. It is, after all, a common trope in science fiction that societies eventually leave their planet behind and spread out into space continuing that process, so that as long as there is more space, our information continues to grow.


If the universe is bigger, doesn’t that mean it contains “more stuff”, more information?

No. Information theory does not define any system to "contain" information intrinsically. Instead, e.g. information theory can consider a system as a message containing information, or it can consider what information needs to be transmitted to inform a receiver about the system, or to update a receiver about changes to the system (more combinations are possible).
In each case, the knowledge of the receiver is an important factor, the geometric size is not.

information in a logical system... formal systems,

For a naive receiver, we can consider that to informed that receiver about a theory, we need to transmit all definitions and axioms. Thus the more definitions or axioms a system is made of, the more data it takes to inform (teach) somebody about it.
However, a non-naive receiver knowing a lot about the given space of formal systems might only need the same of the formal system or a meta-description.
Still, with respect to some such receiver, it is possible to compare any two formal systems by considering how much explanation is required to make that receiver understand each system. But his means for any formal systems A and B, A might require more explanation than B for one receiver, but less than B  for another receiver, so in general this does not yield an objective ordering of the size of systems.
Intuitively, considering some part of astronomy as a logical system, and some part of astrology as a logical system, both using 20 axioms, it would be quick and easy to teach a physics student about the astronomic one the astronomic one but hard to teach the astrological one, whereas for teaching an esoterically interested person, it would be the other way round. While both systems use 20 axioms, information theory considers the receivers expectations, and less surprise means less information to that receiver.
In the same vain, while we might just count axioms, in information theory it would be valid con not consider all axioms as equal in information size. Again, simple axioms could be Small than more complex one, but again unless the receiver expects the complex ones anyways.
Still, in practice we can still compare formal systems in the sense of measuring the average time it requires students to understand the system in the sense that they give correct answers to tests, yielding a scale that intuitively should allow to talk about "easy" versus "hard" to understand theories, which may be a useful approximation if whatever we want to achieve by talking about "size".
